# Dynamic where condition on anonymous object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to implement method with input like this:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> Get(Expression<Func<Class1, Class2, Class3, bool>> predicate)
{ 
   var query = from c1 in db.Class1
               from c2 in db.Class2
               from c3 in db.Class3
               select new { c1, c2, c3 };

  return query.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();

}
```

I want call this method like `Get((x, y, z) => x.Prop1 == 1 && y.Prop5 == 4)`

I've got error:

```
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Class1, Class2, Class3, bool>>' to 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<<anonymous type: Class1 pcp, Class2 pc, Class3 bu>, bool>>'
```

in line containing `Where(predicate)`

How to I solve this issue ?

Comment: ok, now I see it ... you calling where on results instead on sets ... change the query sytntach to method syntax and call Where before Select

Comment: @Selvin what do you mean ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: @Selvin how to I solve this ?

Comment: well, `Where(x=>predicate.Compile()(x.Class1, x.Class2, x.Class3))` would do the thing ... but I don't know if Linq to SQL would be happy

Comment: no it doesnt work

Comment: you have the same error ? or different ... like casting anonymouse class T (which was my previous comment about) or runtime error

Comment: of course it should be `Where(x=>predicate.Compile()(x.c1, x.c2, x.c3))`

Comment: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Class1>()
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: p => DbSet<Class2>(), 
        resultSelector: (p, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<Class1, Class2>(
            Outer = p, 
            Inner = c
        ))
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: ti => DbSet<Class3>(), 
        resultSelector: (ti, c) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Class1, Class2>, Class3>(
            Outer = ti, 
            Inner = c
        ))

Comment: [proof that it compiles](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6uT76d) .. (of course it will not work when EF will try to translate to the SQL)

Comment: [this should work wit EF L2SQL translation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X7iQjc)

Comment: What is `T` here `Task<IList<T>>`? Because even if you solve `Where` problem, then you'll have similar compilation problem with return value (since you cannot provide anonymous type as `T`). This has no solution, declare normal class with 3 properties and use it for both return type, new inside select, and in `Expression<Func<ResultType, bool>>`.

Comment: @Selvin it looks good but I have select new { c1, c2, c3 } and you have select (c1, c2, c3). I have error "An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal."

Comment: ok, seems like EF doesn't support `ValueTuple` ... But AFAIK it should support normal `Tuple` [try this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I7WnxV) ...

Comment: of course your query doesn't make any sens as its CROSS JOIN ... and if there are relationships betwwen Class1, Class2 and Class3 there is better way to do predicate just as `Expression<Func<Class1, bool>>` ... and in Class1 there shoul be set(or single - depends on relationship) of related record from Class2 and Class3(or in Class2 to Class3 - depends on relationship) ... `Where(x => x.Prop1 && x.Class2Relationship.Any(y=> y.Prop5 == 4))`

Comment: C# is a language of types. `Queryable.Where` takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which is incompatible with the `predicate` parameter's type of `Expression<Func<a,b,c,bool>>`. You will need to create an adapter to convert `predicate` into something suitable for `Where` - if you were working in `Enumerable` / `Func`, it would be something like `x => predicate(x.c1, x.c2, x.c3)` but when working with `Expression` you'll need to do parameter substitution.

Comment: Note also that it isn't possible to define `T` in `Get`'s return type - generic types must be explicitly specified or be inferable from one of the parameters. The simplest solution to these issues is to explicitly define a container type `Class CAns { Class1 c1, Class2 c2, Class3 c3 }` and use it in the `select` and in the `Func` parameter for `predicate`: `Expression<Func<CAns, bool>> predicate`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it isn't possible to have your `Get` method return the anonymous type and you don't pass the anonymous type in (e.g. with an answer constructor `Expression` for type inference), you can't use an anonymous type for your query.

Instead create an explicit type and use that for both:

```
public class CAns {
    public Class1 c1;
    public Class2 c2;
    public Class3 c3;
}

async Task<IList<CAns>> Get(Expression<Func<CAns, bool>> predicate)
{
   var query = from c1 in db.Class1
               from c2 in db.Class2
               from c3 in db.Class3
               select new CAns { c1 = c1, c2 = c2, c3 = c3 };

  return query.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
}
```

Then you can call `Get` with:

```
var ans = Get(q => q.c1.Prop1 == 1 && q.c2.Prop5 == 4);
```